# Global variables/array question

Tags: javascript, html

```
Users = new Array;
Passwords = new Array;

function LogIn() {
    Users[10] = "username"
    Passwords[10] = "password"
    Username = user.value;
    Password = pass.value;

    for (i = 0; i <= Users.length; i++) {
    if (Users[i] == Username) {
        if (Passwords[i] == Password) {
            alert("yay!");
        } else
        {
            alert("nay");
        }   
    }
    }
}

function Register() {
    Username = user.value;
    Password = pass.value;

    Users.push(Username);
    Passwords.push(Password);
}
```

Alright, so I'm teaching myself Javasctipt in my free time and I decided that the best way would be to just mess around with it for a while. I am trying, currently, to build a primative "log in"/"register" webpage/function and I've obviously run into a few problems.

Global variables. I need the arrays "Users" and "Passwords" to be global, but the way I have it set up now, I think they are initialized every single time I call the function-set. So, I guess I'll ask both my questions like this: I realize that arrays probably aren't the best thing for a project like this, however, how do I get the values I store in the arrays to persist from run to run?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="LogIn.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Register.js"></script>

<body>
Username: <input type="text" id="user" /> 
Password: <input type="password" id="pass" /> 
<input type="button" value="Log In" onClick="LogIn()"/>
<input type="button" value="Register" onClick="Register()" />
<hr />
</body>
```

Comment: the vars will persist for the life of the page. Until you refresh and/or move off the page, they'll stick around. If you need them to persist over refreshes/navigation, you'll have to use a cookie.

Comment: @Marc B Ok, that's what I thought. However, I'm creating numerous arrays of undefined length with values at [10] - that's my main question.

Comment: just as an aside... I know this is all testing and learning and all, but never have form password validation on the client side in a real production website... just say'n.

Answer (score 0):

It was kind of difficult to understand what you're asking for, but I think this will point you in the right direction:

```
Users = new Array;
Passwords = new Array;

Users[0] = "john";
Users[1] = "sue";
Users[2] = "jack";

Passwords[0] = "blue";
Passwords[1] = "black";
Passwords[2] = "green";

function LogIn() {
   //login logic here
}
```

Comment: Basically, I have two functions: LogIn and Register. Depending on which button I press on the web page, I want it to do either of the above. Register pushes a value to the last spot in the array, in this case, slot 11. When I call the "Register" function the first time, it creates a new array for usernames and passwords (it's supposed to). When I call either function after that, instead of accessing the array created in the previous step, it creates a new array, again. Basically, I'm trying to create a variable once, when the page loads or when I first call something, and then use that.

Answer (score 0):

pretty close

```
Users = new Array();
Passwords = new Array();

function LogIn() {
    Username = document.getElementById("user").value;
    Password = document.getElementById("pass").value;

    for (i = 0; i <= Users.length; i++) {
        if (Users[i] == Username) {
            if (Passwords[i] == Password) {
                alert("yay!");
            } else
            {
                alert("nay");
            }   
        }
    }
}

function Register() {
    Username = document.getElementById("user").value;
    Password = document.getElementById("pass").value;

    Users.push(Username);
    Passwords.push(Password);

}
```

just need a little tweaking.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just curious as to why? Is that just proper syntax or is that required? Because my code _works_, just not the way I'd like it to.

Comment: @tylersebastian `Users[10] = "username"` sets the tenth `Users` string in the array to `"usrname"` and the `Username = user.value;` has no effect because `user` is not defined as a js object.  Thus you have to "get" the object with `document.getElementById` or `document.getElementsByClass` or similar.  Just a logic error and a few syntax errors. :)

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit hard to understand.  Web pages are stateless and values stored in javascript will only persist until the page is reloaded.

For your experiment, if you wanted to do some type of persistence across page loads you should look at something like using cookies.